# Is $H$ a normal subgroup in $A_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H=\{(1),(123),(132)\}$.

Writing all the left and right cosets of $H$ and $A_5$ would be too monotonous. $A_5$ has 60 elements! So how else can I conclude whether $H$ is a normal subgroup or not?

Comment: $$(124)(123)(142)=(243)\notin H$$

Comment: Have you seen the proof that $A_5$ is simple?

Comment: @Timbuc could you expand on that? Why does $(243)$ need to be in $H$?

Comment: because normal subgroups are closed under conjugation by any element in the group

Comment: @Gage I just took a look at it. So the only normal subgroups $A_5$ has are itself and the trivial subgroup.

Comment: Yes, $A_n$ is simple for all $n\geq5$

Comment: If $H$ was a normal subgroup of $A_5$ then $(243) \in H$, but it isn't, so $H$ is not a normal subgroup of $A_5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal subgroups are characterized by the fact that left cosets $gH$ equal the corresponding right cosets $Hg$ for any $g \in G$. So hint: take $g=(14)$ and calculate the left and right coset associated with this element for your subgroup $H$.

Comment: How did you know to take $(14)$? Trial and error?

Comment: No, in $A_5$ there is a lot of room to move the numbers around. Since $H$ uses 1,2, and 3, I tried $(14)$ to "get $H$ out of its comfort zone".